# How I can convert date object into time in symfony2

Tags: date, datetime, symfony

I am using Symfony2. While fetching date from database, I need to display date in my `index.html.php` .

When I am printing its displaying like this: `DateTime Object ( [date] => 2012-10-09 13:30:23 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )`

But when I'm converting object to int its giving error: `$days2 = floor( $entities->getCreationDate() / (60 * 60 * 24));`

```
Notice: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int**
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get an integer timestamp from a DateTime object use the [getTimeStamp method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 5):

I'll add this as a second answer, since it's very different than my previous.

To get the difference between two dates in PHP, you may want to consider using PHP's built-in DateTime and DateInterval classes.

The following code will get you the difference, in days, between the creation date and today:

```
$creationDate = $entity->getCreationDate();
$now = new \DateTime();

$interval = $creationDate->diff($now);

echo "The difference is " . $interval->days . " days.";
```

Further documentation on DateInterval: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display a DateTime object in Twig is to use Twig's built-in `date` function:

```
{{ entity.creationDate | date("m/d/Y") }}
```

You can actually use any format that's supported by the native PHP function `strtotime()`, so you can customize how you want it to appear. Here are some examples with the instance you referenced above:

```
{{ entity.creationDate | date("m/d/Y") }}
--> Prints: "10/09/2012"

{{ entity.creationDate | date("Y-m-d") }}
--> Prints: "2012-10-09"

{{ entity.creationDate | date("H:i") }}
--> Prints: "13:30"
```

More info on this Twig function here:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am using .html.php template not twig.
I have to display days from added date.

Comment: @AlokJain why then your question is tagged as `Twig`?

Comment: @thecatontheflat My bad; I added that tag. Removing it now.