# How to get difference between two Dates in Symfony MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, odm

I have a problem with calculate dates difference between a PHP date object and current time.I know that i must get current time with this:

```
//in a symfony controller
new \DateTime("now")
```

and i have a Member Document(entity in MySql) that has a field like this :

```
class Member {
    //some fields

    /**
     * @ODM\Date
     */
    protected $regDate;

    //and so on
}
```

Now i want to calculate user activity :

```
// $member declared and assigned
$activity = new \DateTime("now") - $member->getRegDate();
```

But this error occurs:

```
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int
```

What mistake i do?Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can convert date object into time in symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803127/how-i-can-convert-date-object-into-time-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `date_diff` to calculate the difference:

```
$diff = date_diff(new DateTime(), $member->getRegDate());
var_dump( $diff ); // « shows some properties.
```

For more information, see the documentation on [date_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) and [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

BTW, you don't need to use `"now"` either, as that is the default behaviour.